# Java Compiler Script [Mac]

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am trying to create to create a script that will automatically change the working directory to my Java code and then compile the code. I am able to change the directly to my path but I cannot figure out how to to call the java compiler on the "filename" while taking the "filename" as an argument directly from the Terminal.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILE = “$1”
    open -a Terminal /Users/Jarvis/Desktop/Codes/Java/CS\ 49J/
    javac “$FILE”
```

Comment: Why do you need to open the terminal app?

Comment: Because after compiling, I want to be able to run the compiled file directly.

Comment: Your script opens an entire new terminal windowing and does nothing in it. Do you understand how bash scripts and subprocesses work?

Comment: I do a little bit. My whole idea was to compile the java file and then be able to run it directly from the terminal. I don't want to CD to that specific folder, thereby I have the open -a terminal

Comment: You don't need to cd if you just give the entire path. All your current script does is compile. You'll want more lines if you want to start the Java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your `FILE` assignment. Also, as @cricket_007 mentions, you don't need to open the terminal app, just change directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
cd /Users/Jarvis/Desktop/Codes/Java/CS\ 49J/
javac "$FILE"
```

Alternatively (I'm in the habit of using curly braces around variables):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
WORKING_DIR="/Users/Jarvis/Desktop/Codes/Java/CS\ 49J/"
javac "${WORKING_DIR}${FILE}"
```

Comment: I believe this will exit the terminal after compiling. What if I want to stay in the same directly after auto compiling allowing me to execute it?

Comment: The script executes in a sub-shell, so you're right, you won't be left in the directory where the file exists.

Comment: Maybe you could extend the script to run `java -jar program.jar` after compiling?